# Contour Integral About A Circle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, winding-number

I have $\int_\delta \frac{z}{z^3 -1} dz$, where $\delta(t) = (\frac{1}{2})e^{it
}$ with $t \in [0, 2\pi]$.  It's clear that the winding number is $Ind_\delta(z_0) = 1$, where $z_0 = 0$. I'm just unsure of how to rewrite the integral so that I can use Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Try Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: Alternatively, $f(z) = \frac{z^2}{z^3-1}$.

Comment: Is f(z) = z/(z^3 -1) analytic?  And I'm a little unsure of what you're getting at with the alternative.

Comment: $\frac{z}{z^3-1}$ is analytic except at - where?

Comment: At 1, but it's not continuous there.  Isn't that a requirement for Cauchy's theorem?  That any points where the function is not analytic, the function be at least continuous?

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's Integral theorem:

$$\int\limits_\delta\frac z{z^3-1}dz=0\;\;\text{since}\;\;\frac z{z^3-1}\;\;\text{analytic on}\;\delta\;\;\text{and within it}$$